# How do we know if a multivariable function is invertible?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

A question about multivariable functions.
How do we know if a multivariable function(or transform) is invertible?
I mean just like we know y=2x is reversible and has an invert but y=x^2 is not invertible.
What about multivariable functions? I've already known that we can determine if a matrix is reversible according to its determinant, but what about a nonlinear transform, and is it has anything to do with Jacobian matrix?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you are looking for is "invertible." There is a relationship between invertibility and the Jacobian, and it is the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Ahaha, I've revised my question, sorry for thatI'm not a native speaker, and they means quite the same in my language. Thank you, and I'm gonna google the terms you mentioned.

Comment: @ZYWu no problem, it was clear what you meant.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. The sufficient condition for a multivariable function to be invertible in a neighborhood of a point in its domain is that its Jacobian determinat is nonzero! Just the same as what I thought before! But, furthermore, what if it's not for a neighborhood but the entire domain? What should we do to determine?